# function that returns a 2d array of int and string - Go

Tags: go, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to create a function that returns a 2D array that stores and integer value and a string value. Obviously i can just use a normal array like i would in python as go uses data types.

I've looked into using a struct but i don't know if I'm missing something or not but I've deleted my small bit of code about 5 times and got nowhere, is anyone able to point me in the right direction please, i feel like I'm getting nowhere...

```
type user_info struct{
id int
name string
}

new_user := []user_info{{id: 1, name: "Max"}}
```

This will create one instance but how to i create a single array that i can append the new user to?

Comment: You cannot append to an array, but you already have a single slice which you can append a new value to. What problem are you having here exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to save all the values in one array or slice(sorry im still getting my head around these) so i can return it, for example, i have a loop that will increment each time and i want to add the new value each loop and once the loop has ended to return everything in one go. However i can seem to figure out how to
 add everything together so i can return it all at once
```
e.g.

mixed_value array/slice

for i:= 0; i< 10;i++{
//append here
}
return  mixed_value array/slice
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say here. I suggest going through the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/) which covers most of the language fundamentals, maybe the [`append` example](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/15) specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have multiple ways to appned:

```
new_user := []user_info{
    {id: 1, name: "Max"},
    {id: 2, name: "John"},
    {id: 3, name: "George"},
}
```

or you can append item by item:

```
new_user = append(new_user, user_info{id: 4, name: "Sam"})
```

Comment: yep, thats what i was after. Turns out when i was trying to append i was using
append(new_user, urser_info()) . Thanks very much!